# Plotting large graph in R with igraph

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph

I was trying to plot a network with 200 thousands nodes and 8 millions edges. The code I used was here:

```
library(igraph)
file.choose()
xlist<-read.graph("/Users/quyao/Desktop/redstar_relation.txt", format="ncol", directed=TRUE)
xlist
png('my_png.png', width = 1600, height =900)
plot(xlist)
dev.off()
```

I got this:

[image]

It's hard to study the topology with this kind of picture. Do you have any suggestions?

As there are too many nodes and edges, change the layout through the parameter 'layout' may not be so helpful.

Constructing this picture took about one and half hours using my code, how could i make it faster?

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you give us some kind of data to work with?   Currently we can't reproduce your graph.

Comment: It's going to be hard to study 200k nodes visually without splitting up/merging the data.

Comment: I dare guessing that visualizing such a large network will not be get you anywhere you want to go. You'd be better off by first defining what you are looking for and what you try to study, then either split your data or make some pre-processing of your data, computing some statistics, or aggregations or whatever - and only then visualize whatever aspect of the graph/analysis that will be intelligible and helpful in making your point. you will also save yourself the wait for the graph to print.

Comment: Thanks to you all. @amit is right, I'd better to clear what I am looking for and trying to study first and make some pre-processing before plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using another software for visualization. I generally use Gephi for graphs with a magnitude up to 150 000 nodes.

However it really depends on how much RAM your machine has (mine has 8 GB). There is also the possibility to expand RAM allocation to Gephi by modifying their configuration file (it is not allocated automatically like in RStudio.

Comment: So what do you do with more than 150k nodes?

Comment: You can either "prune" your data and filter the nodes that are less signifcant based on their betweenness or degree, or you can increase the ram of your laptop. Unfortunately graph computation is very RAM intensive.